# (lmgrd) Connection attempt to redundant server failed

Tags: licensing

I am trying to setup a triad of redundant servers for licensing with FlexNET's licensing tool. Currently I've got a test license from my vendor. Starting the servers works fine, license works.

The actual problem is, that two of my computers don't find each other, but recognize the third computer in the triad. While they connect easily with the mentioned third computer (but it is the second in the list of MACs in the license files), they tell me "(lmgrd) Connection attempt to primary redundant server [xxx] failed" respectively "Connection attempt to tertiary redundant server [yyy] failed".

I already checked whether they can ping each other with their alias names ([xxx], [yyy]). That works and they are both listed in the others */etc/hosts*. All three log files and the license file (it's the same on all three computers) is attached to this message. Feel free to ask me further questions to solve my problem.

Since I can post only two links until I've got enough reputation (that is hard to earn with limited function access), I'll post my license file and the log of one of the two computers which don't connect. The other log looks similar.

PS: schwalbe is the forced master server which can't connect with habicht, reiher is the server which detects and connects with both other servers, habicht is the slave that can't connect to schwalbe.

[License File](https://ufile.io/4fmcr)
[Log_server1](https://ufile.io/mqtyl)

PPS: I know the license is already expired, but the problem occured before the expiration date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** I had to disable firewalls on both computers ([xxx], [yyy]. Now it works fine on all three servers.